# SQL Server stored procedure to add days to a date

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to write a stored procedure that given a date and a number of working days, adds those given days to that date, and returns the new date, without counting the non-working days and the weekends. the non-working day are stored in another table.

It's my second stored procedure so I'm not quite familiar with the lexic, so, sorry in advance if you find obvious mistakes.

So far I've gotten to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DateAdd
     (@GivenDate DATE, @DaysToAdd int)
    DECLARE   @ReturnDate DATE,
    DECLARE   @Counter int,
    DECLARE   @NextDate DATE
AS     
    SET @Counter = 0
    SET @ReturnDate = @GivenDate
    SET @NextDate = @GivenDate
    GO  

    WHILE (@Counter < @DaysToAdd)
        @Counter + 1 

        IF(datepart(weekday, @FechaVariable) !=6 && 
           datepart(weekday, @FechaVariable) != 7) 
            IF(#TODO-- call the query and check it with @NextDate) 
            @FechaRetorno = DateAdd(dd, 1, @FechaRetorno) 
        ELSE IF @NextDate = DateAdd(dd, 1, @NextDate)   
        EN IF
    END WHILE

    -- I don't know where to put this query, or how to call ir from the IF
    SELECT Date 
    FROM non_working_days 
    WHERE Date = $Variable 

    RETURN @FechaRetorno
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Tally/Calendar table would to the trick as well, but you can to do this with an ad-hoc tally table.  Also, this approach would be faster than an recursive cte.

One additonal option is that you can exclude HOLIDAYS by adding the following to the WHERE clause.

```
   and D not in ('2017-12-25','2018-01-01')
```

**The SQL**

```
Declare @Date date = '2017-04-01'
Declare @Days int = 5


Select D
 From (
        Select D,RN=Row_Number() over (Order by D)
         From (Select Top ((@Days*2)+10) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By Number),@Date) From  master..spt_values ) A
         Where DateName(WEEKDAY,D) not in ('Saturday','Sunday')
      ) A
 Where RN=@Days
```

**Returns**

```
2017-04-07
```

Answer (score 1):

Here. Assuming the other table is called OtherTable and the column of dates to avoid is called DatesToAvoid, this will add one day at a time to your date, and if that date is not a weekend or in the DatesToAvoid, it will decrement @DaysToAdd. Once @DaysToAdd reaches 0, it stops.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DateAddsp(@GivenDate DATE, @DaysToAdd int)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE @DaystoAdd > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @GivenDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@GivenDate)
        SET @DaysToAdd = CASE
            WHEN @GivenDate IN (SELECT DatesToAvoid FROM OtherTable) OR DATEPART(DW,@GivenDate) IN (1,7) /* Saturday or Sunday*/
                THEN @DaysToAdd
            ELSE @DaysToAdd + 1
        END
    END
    RETURN DATEADD(DW, @DaysToAdd, @GivenDate);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You're are overcomplicating things. The function which you need to use is dateadd: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql

Try something along the lines of the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DateAddsp(@GivenDate DATE, @DaysToAdd int)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEADD(DW, @DaysToAdd, @GivenDate);
END
```

You cannot use dateadd as the name for the stored proc, as it is a reserved word in SQL Server - it is the name of the function which I just utilized above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm using the DATEADD, but I need to take account of every day but weekends, and a few dates I have in another table.

Comment: Can you please post sample data from that table?

Comment: the table contains a single column of dates. nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a procedure, this is an in-line table-valued function to get the result of adding working days to a date.

```
create function dbo.udf_add_working_days (@Date date, @Days int)
returns table with schemabinding as return (
with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, days as (
  select top (1000)
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@date))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo 
  order by [Date]
)
, working_days as (
  select top (@Days) 
    [Date]
  from days
  where datename(weekday,[date]) not in ('Saturday','Sunday')
    /* -- put your non working days table info here and uncomment this clause
    and not exists (
      select 1
      from dbo.HolidayTable h
      where days.[Date] = h.HolidayDate
      )
    --*/
  order by [Date]
)
select top 1 [date] 
from working_days
order by [Date] desc
);
go
```

and you would call it like so:

```
select [date]
from dbo.udf_add_working_days('20170401',10)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ITXB6884

returns:

```
+------------+
|    date    |
+------------+
| 2017-04-14 |
+------------+
```

Or you can call it using dates from a query using `cross apply()`

```
select ... 
  , x.Date as NewWorkDate
from t
  dbo.udf_add_working_days (t.[Date], t.[NumberOfDays]) as x
```

Reference on inline table valued functions

- [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/)
- [Inline Scalar Functions - Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions)
- [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance: An entertaining title for a boring post - Adam Machanic](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/)
- [TSQL User-Defined Functions: Ten Questions You Were Too Shy To Ask - Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/tsql-user-defined-functions-ten-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)